# Make firestore not reload anytime

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm actually working alone on an application and it's a bit difficult for the documentation.

Here is my problem: I have this code

```
/**
 * @param postId
 * @param query
 */
public getCommentToPost(postId: string): Observable<CommentModel[]> {
  return this.afStore.collection('posts')
    .doc(postId).collection<CommentModel>('comments').valueChanges();
}
```

`afStore` is a reference to AngularFirestore; (I'm using `angularfire2`).

The thing is that all the output is being merely reloaded each time there's a modification in the final collection (here `comments`).

It still very fast, but I can see the small loading spinner sometimes on other comments which aren't even modified.

Is it possible to load only the new comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any update to a collection/query in Firestore, you get the affected documents *and* the type of change that was made to that document, i.e whether it was added, changed, or deleted. In AngularFire2 that information is mapped to a [`DocumentChangeAction`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#the-documentchangeaction-type). But the `valueChanges` doesn't get a `DocumentChangeAction` so the information on the type of change isn't available there. Use one of the other streaming methods (i.e. `snapshotChanges`) to know what type of change was made.

Comment: Thank you for the accurate answer ! I understand what you're talking about. I've already looked at it but I don't know if the array won't be totally updated, but it was much better for what I've seen.